# Cosmos DB returns unexpected value 'filter' in continuation token

Tags: c#, .net-core, pagination, azure-cosmosdb

I have following json object:

```
  {
    "id": "9df7d70e-1b07-4080-ac9e-964332c93a89",
    "name": "some name",
    "ranking": {
         "A": 1,
         "B": 2,
     }
  }
```

I want to get items **sorted by ranking** depending on the key **A** or **B** using **pagination**.

The query I am using for this:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ... ORDER BY c.ranking['A'] ASC
```

Pagination params:

```
FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions()
        {
            MaxItemCount = cosmosDbSettings.PageResultsCount,
            RequestContinuation = continuationToken,
            EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
        };
```

Trigger cosmos db:

```
      var docQuery = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(cosmosDbSettings.DatabaseId, collectionId),
            new SqlQuerySpec(query, sqlParameters),
            feedOptions)
            .AsDocumentQuery();
        var results = new PagedResources();
        List<dynamic> resources = new List<dynamic>();
        var queryResult = await docQuery.ExecuteNextAsync();

        while (queryResult.Count == 0 && docQuery.HasMoreResults)
        {
            queryResult = await docQuery.ExecuteNextAsync();
        }

        if (!queryResult.Any())
        {
            return results;
        }
```

For the **first and the second page** it works OK, then suddenly some items are missing in response.

At the end of the token **filter** is appears

```
filter":"c.ranking[\"A\"] >= 2"
```

Whole token:

```
[{"compositeToken":{"token":"+RID:~oClCAPq5X0KLAAAAAAAAAA==#RT:2#TRC:20#RTD:GQD5+RFVofBwed+BlCvhBMAU#ISV:2#IEO:65551#FPC:AgEAAAAcAHMAwP1gHxAAUgB4ABgAEQAAGDaA4wAcAABgwkM=","range":{"min":"","max":"05C1DFFFFFFFFC"}},"orderByItems":[{"item":5}],"rid":"oClCAPq5X0KMAAAAAAAAAA==","skipCount":0,"filter":"c.ranking[\"A\"] >= 2"}]
```

Maybe I am missing something, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It should be "filter":"c.ranking[\"A\"] >= 2", you are missing double inverted commas at the front

Comment: @noobprogrammer thanks for the replay!
Do you mean to change the query 
from
ORDER BY c.ranking['A'] 
to 
ORDER BY c.ranking["A"]  ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you write. Can you tell how are you getting the token? If you are able to edit the token then write "filter":"c.ranking["A"] >= 2" like this.

Comment: @noobprogrammer nope, that '\' is required when using "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you drain all the query results ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.feediterator?view=azure-dotnet#examples)):

```
while (docQuery.HasMoreResults)
{
    var queryResult = await docQuery.ExecuteNextAsync();
    resources.AddRange(queryResult);
}

return resources;
```

Also the content of the continuation token is opaque, whatever it contains is meant for the query engine to use on the next time you want to resume. If you drain all the results (as I showed), it will be `null`.